# How to convert List to List of tuples?

Tags: list, tuples, erlang

I want to convert `[z,z,a,z,z,a,a,z]` to `[{z,2},{a,1},{z,2},{a,2},{z,1}]`. How can I do it?

So, I need to accumulate previous value, counter of it and list of tuples.

I've create record

```
-record(acc, {previous, counter, tuples}).
```

Redefined

```
listToTuples([]) -> [];
listToTuples([H | Tail]) -> 
    Acc = #acc{previous=H, counter=1},
    listToTuples([Tail], Acc).
```

But then I have some trouble

```
listToTuples([H | Tail], Acc) ->   
    case H == Acc#acc.previous of
        true  ->
        false ->
    end.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you build up your answer (Acc) in reverse, the previous will be the head of that list.

here's how i would do it --

```
list_pairs(List) -> list_pairs(List, []).

list_pairs([], Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
list_pairs([H|T], [{H, Count}|Acc]) -> list_pairs(T, [{H, Count+1}|Acc]);
list_pairs([H|T], Acc) -> list_pairs(T, [{H, 1}|Acc]).
```

*(i expect someone will now follow with a one-line list comprehension version..)*

Comment: I doubt you can do this with a list comprehension. You need a fold at least.

Answer (score 6):

I would continue on the road building the list in reverse. Notice the pattern matching over X on the first line.

```
F = fun(X,[{X,N}|Rest]) -> [{X,N+1}|Rest];
       (X,Rest)         -> [{X,1}|Rest] end.

lists:foldr(F,[],List).
```

Comment: Use `lists:foldr/3` and you are home. ;)

Comment: With `lists:foldr/3` you are not really building in the lists in reverse, at least not in the same way as is meant when you call use an accumulator and call `lists:reverse/1` on it. `lists:foldr` just works on the list from right to left so it processes all the elements in reverse order, which it is **defined** to do. It is not tail-recursive which is not always such a bad thing. This is mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally use `lists:foldr/3` or do it by hand with something like:

```
list_to_tuples([H|T]) -> list_to_tuples(T, H, 1);
list_to_tuples([]) -> [].

list_to_tuples([H|T], H, C) -> list_to_tuples(T, H, C+1);
list_to_tuples([H|T], P, C) -> [{P,C}|list_to_tuples(T, H, 1);
list_to_tuples([], P, C) -> [{P,C}].
```

Using two accumulators saves you unnecessarily building and pulling apart a tuple for every element in the list. I find writing it this way clearer.